# Collection of classes which implement a certain interface

Tags: java, interface, constructor, java.lang.class

I'm stuggling for some hours with this problem and I hope that you can help me out.

I have a interface which defines some methods:

```
public interface LanguageInterface {
         //...
}
```

There is a class which implement the LanguageInterface

```
public class ZPL implements LanguageInterface {
    // ...
}
```

And now I want to create an enum which contains all those classes.

```
public enum PrintingLanguage {
   ZPL(ZPL.class);

   private Class<LanguageInterface> clazz;

   PrintingLanguage(Class<LanguageInterface> clazz) {
      this.clazz = clazz;
}
```

And now I always get an eclipse which says

> The constructor PrintingLanguage(Class< ZPL >) is undefined

I simply want to allow the constructor to accept only classes which implements this interface.

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You want `Class<? extends LanguageInterface>`, to allow any type parameter that extends the interface.

Comment: interface and extends work together ? should LanguageInterface be a class and not an interface ?

Comment: @wrongAnswer: Generic variance doesn't distinguish between interfaces and classes.

Comment: @user2948795 if this is the correct answer please mark it as correct when you can i think its after 15 mins you asked the question ...